# How to create a shortcut to start, minimize and bring programs to the foreground

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I just switched to Linux and I am setting up my laptop. In windows, I use an AutoHotkey shortcut, to do the following:
 - Open "chrome" when it is not active.
 - Minimize "chrome" when it in the foreground.
 - Bring it to the foreground when the window is not active.

I use the following code in "Autokey" which works nicely but I would love it if I can do this with a simple bash script:

```
#AutoKey script to toggle any windowed application, Nautilus as the example. Requires xdotool and wmctrl.
import subprocess
command = 'wmctrl -lx'
output = system.exec_command(command, getOutput=True)  

if 'google-chrome' in output:
    winClass = window.get_active_class()
    if winClass == 'google-chrome.Google-chrome':
        system.exec_command("xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool getactivewindow)")
    else:
        system.exec_command("wmctrl -x -a google-chrome")

else:
    system.exec_command("google-chrome")
#end script
```

Now I tried to translate this to bash code but I get stuck in checking if chrome is running in the foreground. I had the following pseudocode in mind but I can not find the right shell commands:

```
if chrome is not open
   open chrome
else
   if chrome is on foreground
      minimize chrome
   else
      bring chrome to foreground
end
```

I tried to do obtain this behaviour in Linux by using a shell script in the Linux "shortcut" application. But up till now, I was not able to find a way to check if Google-chrome is in the foreground. I tried using the "xdotools" package but this doesn't seem to work:

```
if ($(xdotool search --name "Google Chrome") -eq $(xdotool getactivewindow))
     xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool getactivewindow)
else
     wmctrl -x -a google-chrome
end
```

Do you maybe have some tips on what is the best way to achieve this? I now have the following ingredients:

To open google-chrome I use:

```
google-chrome &
```

To minimize google-chrome I use:

```
xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool getactivewindow)
```

To maximize google-chrome I use:

```
wmctrl -x -a google-chrome
```

And I think I need to use something like this to check if chrome is on foreground:

```
wmctrl -lx
xdotool search --name "Google Chrome"
xdotool getactivewindow
enter code here
```

Thanks a lot in advance,
Greetings,
Rick,

System information:
Desktop: Hp Zbook G3 studio
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (development branch)
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received the answer to my question from a user on [another forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390045&p=13761602#post13761602).

```
#!/bin/bash

chromefocus=$(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname | grep -c "Google Chrome")

if [ "$chromefocus" -gt "0" ]; then
        xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool getactivewindow)
    else
        wmctrl -xa "google-chrome.Google-chrome" || /usr/bin/google-chrome
fi
```